# Adding one to the highest serial number found in search

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

When a serial number is present do nothing, when a serial number is not present search through our database and add one to the highest serial number found. My code is not adding one when. So I just keep getting the same number. 
 When a serial number is present do nothing, when a serial number is not present search through our database and add one to the highest serial number found. My code is not adding one when. So I just keep getting the same number.

```
 // Is there a current serial number? If yes, use that sequence number else generate a new one.
        var currentSerialNumber = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecordbcs_arm_serial');
        if (currentSerialNumber == null || currentSerialNumber == '')
            {
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','NUmber of REcords3','here');
            // ok - serial number is blank - let'g get a new sequence number
                var SerialNo = nextSerialNo();

            } else {
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','NUmber of REcords4','here');
                // a serial number has already been issued - use it's sequence number
                var SerialNo = currentSerialNumber.substring(10,14);

            }




        var modulecode = 'ARM';
        var tmpSubscription = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecordbcs_arm_c');
        if (tmpSubscription == 'T') {
            var subscription = true;
        } else {
            var subscription = false;
        }
        if (subscription == true) {
          isSubscription = true;
          serialtype = 'C';
        } else {
          isSubscription = false;
        }
        // calculating the final serial number 
        var finalserialnumber = (serialtype + HashKey + months + year + modulecode + SerialNo);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Final Serial',finalserialnumber);
        // calculating the unlock key
        var unlockkey = Getunlockforuser(companyname, finalserialnumber, isSubscription);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Unlock',unlockkey);
        // this is placing the serial number and unlock key into the fields in netsuite.
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecordbcs_arm_unlock',unlockkey);
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecordbcs_arm_serial',finalserialnumber);
        //

        }




        function nextSerialNo(){
            // this function will calculate the serial number based off the highest record found in netsuite
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','NUmber of REcords1','here');
            var filters = new Array();
            filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive',null,'is','F');
            filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_bcs_cm_lapse',null,'is','F');
            filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecordbcs_arm_serial',null,'isnotempty','F');

            var columns = new Array();
            columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
            columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecordbcs_arm_serial');


            var highNumber = 0;
            var allUnlockKeys = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_bcs_contracts',null,filters,columns);


            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','NUmber of REcords','null');

            for (var i=0; allUnlockKeys != null && i < allUnlockKeys.length; i++)
            {

                var x  = Number(allUnlockKeys[i].getValue(columns[1]).substring(10,14));
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','value of x',x.toString());
                if (x > highNumber){
                        highNumber = x+1;
                 }
             }

                return padstring(highNumber,4);
          }
```

Comment: Need some more information here I think to give an accurate answer. Is there a particular reason you are only using a portion of the returned serial number for comparison? Why not compare the entire serial number to highNumber? How many total records are there in the 'customrecord_bcs_contracts' custom record? I ask becuase nlapistSearchRecord can at most return 1000 results. Why arent you using grouping/summing in the search? You could just use this to get the highest number directly from the search: new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecordbcs_arm_serial',null,"MAX"); No need to loop through results

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would suggest moving to SuiteScript 2.0.   Thant being said, here is a quick and dirty attempt to answer your question, since I'm not 100% sure what your data looks like.  I also parsed the number as an integer to ensure that it is a number.  I would add in some testing on that as well, in a production version.  Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

In short, use your search, but sort descending by the field that you want to add to (thus your first result should be the current highest).  You can also do this in a saved search, and just load that search, looking only at the first row.

```
require(['N/search'],function(search){
  function nextSerialNo(){
    log.debug('NUmber of REcords1','here');
    var highNumber=0;
    var resultArray=[];
    var contractlineSearchObj=search.create({
      type:"customrecord_bcs_contracts",
      filters:[["isinactive","is",false],"and",["custrecord_bcs_cm_lapse","is",false],"and",["custrecordbcs_arm_serial","isnotempty"]],
      columns:[
        search.createColumn({
          name:"internalid",
        }),
        search.createColumn({
          name:"custrecordbcs_arm_serial",
          sort:search.Sort.DESC
       })
      ]
    }).run().each(function(result){
      log.debug('result: ',JSON.stringify(result));
      var highNumber=result.getValue({name:'custrecordbcs_arm_serial'});
      log.debug('highNumber1: ',JSON.stringify(highNumber));

      var highNumber=highNumber.toString().substring(2,3);
      log.debug('highNumber2: ',JSON.stringify(highNumber));

      var highNumber=parseInt(highNumber)+1;
      log.debug('highNumber3: ',JSON.stringify(highNumber));
      return false
    });

    return padstring(highNumber,4);
  }

  nextSerialNo()
});
```

Also, here is the main page to the 2.0 modules: [SuiteScript 2.0 Modules](https://debugger.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4220488571.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.